# In what case the contravariance of function arguments is useful?

Tags: types, contravariance

We know that for two function types T<sub>1</sub>→T<sub>2</sub> and S<sub>1</sub>→S<sub>2</sub>, T<sub>1</sub>→T<sub>2</sub> ≤ S<sub>1</sub>→S<sub>2</sub> iff S<sub>1</sub>≤T<sub>1</sub> and T<sub>2</sub>≤S<sub>2</sub> ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping#Function_types)). But I cannot come up with a realistic case where we want S<sub>1</sub>≤T<sub>1</sub>, as more likely we will use template/generic type to get around the Liskov substitution principle.

To facilitate the discussion, let's say we have the following classes (in Python)

```py
class Animal: ...

class Cat(Animal): ...

class Habitat: ...

class Forest(Habitat): ...
```

on top of which we have "research center" classes, able to find the habitat for an animal. What *won't* work is

```
class AnimalResearchCenter:
    def find_habitat(self, a: Animal) -> Habitat:
        ...


class CatResearchCenter(AnimalResearchCenter):
    def find_habitat(self, c: Cat) -> Forest:
        ...
```

because the type of the argument of `CatResearchCenter.find_habitat`, `Cat`, should have been a supertype of `Animal`. In fact, mypy will complain

```
error: Argument 1 of "find_habitat" is incompatible with supertype "AnimalResearchCenter";
supertype defines the argument type as "Animal"  [override]
note: This violates the Liskov substitution principle
```

and we should use `Generic` for this case:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", bound=Animal)

class AnimalResearchCenter(Generic[T]):
    def find_habitat(self, a: T) -> Habitat:
        ...


class CatResearchCenter(AnimalResearchCenter[Cat]):
    def find_habitat(self, c: Cat) -> Forest:
        ...
```

So the question is, in what case we will want a method like `find_habitat(self, a: Animal) -> Habitat` in the base class?

Comment: It's just contravariance. No "-ness" needed.

Comment: And the answer to your question is "it is almost never needed/useful in practice".

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Thanks. I corrected the title.